# Memcached stopped working (not found error)

Tags: php, apache, memcached

I'm using memcached ono my website (debian server with apache2), 'im loading it like that:

```
$memcached= new Memcached;
$memcached->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);
```

It worked but today I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Memcached' not found in ...
```

I tried `apt install php-memcached` but it is already installed, what can I check ?

Also tried `apt install memcached`, `service memcached restart`, and `service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem with debian after a simple apt-get upgrade.

it turned out that apt has auto-upgrade php7.4-memcached to php8.0-memcached while php7.4 is running.

so i install php7.4-memcached again and after apache restart its all fine now.